# How to prove a series is greater than zero over an interval?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Show that the series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(x^{2k+1})}{(2k + 1)!}$ is greater than zero for $0<x\leq \sqrt{6}$

For a function to show something was greater than zero over an interval I would differentiate, show there was a maximum (or it is an increasing function) and then show that the two end points were also greater than zero. Since this function is the same as the sine function, I imagine there is an analogous way to do this for a series but can't think how. Can someone explain to me the method I should use, is differentiating again the right option? (Also I wish to do this particularly using series, and do not wish to show by the method I described above using the sine function). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For positive $x$ this is an alternating series.
We can try to combine summands in pairs for even $k$ and odd $k+1$. We obtain
$$ \begin{align}\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}+ \frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^{2k+3}}{(2k+3)!}&=\frac{((2k+3)(2k+2)-x^2)x^{2k+1}}{(2k+3)!}\\&\ge \frac{(6-x^2)x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\ge 0\end{align}$$
with equality only if $k=0$ and $x^2=6$. Therefore all summands (thus combine) are nonnegative and in fact almost all are positive if $0<x\le \sqrt 6$.

Comment: So I kind of understand the method you've taken but in the first equation in this the sum from k = 0 to infinity?

Comment: Oh sorry yes the sum even from k = 0 to infinity, that is perfect thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

There is a clue in the question: where did $\sqrt{6}$ come from?  Sounds like the root of a polynomial...

The goal is to show that for $0 \le x \le \sqrt{6}$,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(x^{2k+1})}{(2k + 1)!}
= x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \cdots \ge x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \ge 0
$$
The second $\ge$ sign should be straightforward.  For the first one, observe that the series is alternating, and show that the terms are decreasing in absolute value.